# How to compute Maximum likelihood of Standard Deviation

Tags: r

What is Maximum likelihood of Standard Deviation? Consider a vector= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}.
How do we compute Maximum likelihood of Deviation?

Comment: Repeating the same words over and over does not a good question make

Comment: What do you mean by "Deviation"?

Comment: Looks like homework to me. I would downvote your question if I could. I believe you are talking about estimating the standard deviation through Maximum Likelihood Estimation. Am I right?

Comment: I did research, can you just help me understand what is Maximum likelihood of Standard Deviation?

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Uncorrected_sample_standard_deviation), the uncorrected standard deviation is the maximum likelihood estimate of the standard deviation for a normally distributed population. Hence:

```
uncorSD <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) {
    if (na.rm) {
        x <- x[!is.na(x)]
    }
    sqrt(sum((x - mean(x))^2) / length(x))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `optim()` for the optimization of the log-likelihood function with `hessian=TRUE` to obtain the Hessian matrix.

Invert it using `solve()` on `objectname$hessian`.

The square root of the diagonal elements of this matrix are the standard errors.

Comment: So you complained about the question and then decided to answer it?  Nice.

Comment: I wonder if the OP researched it and I would feel bad if he did but did not write what he knows/tried as he is a new user. As I said I would downvote if I had enough reputation. Please do it.

Comment: @RichardScriven Never forget what it's like to be low in rep.  You gotta farm those points any time you can.  Once you've got enough rep you can be more picky but I recall a few questions I'm slightly ashamed to associate myself with but I was young and needed rep to score those sweet sweet privileges.

Comment: I'm ashamed of my first 200 answers.  Haha.  And I agree, it's a bad question and I'm a jerk. Forgive me

Answer (score 0):

Use `mle` in the `stats4` package.

```
> mle(function(mu,sigma) -sum(dnorm(1:10,mu, sigma, log = TRUE)), start=list(mu=5, sigma=2)  ) %>% summary
Maximum likelihood estimation

Call:
mle(minuslogl = function(mu, sigma) -sum(dnorm(1:10, mu, sigma, 
    log = TRUE)), start = list(mu = 5, sigma = 2))

Coefficients:
         Estimate   Std. Error
mu    5.500072643 0.9083575442
sigma 2.872478768 0.6423716616

-2 log L: 49.48090277
```

Comment: That seems a long-winded way of computing the SD using division *N* (instead of *N-1*) in the case you show (assuming a normally distributed population).

Comment: But it gives you a std err on the SD (which was how I read the question).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that uses the built in standard deviation function in R and corrects based on the sample size.

```
# returns the MLE standard deviation for a vector x
sd_mle <- function(x){
  x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  n <- length(x)
  sd <- sd(x)
  return(sqrt((n-1)/n)*sd)
}
```

Try it out with a random vector...

```
# create a vector of 15 observations from a standard normal distribution
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(15)

# bias corrected standard deviation
sd(x) # [1] 1.017695

# MLE (not bias corrected) standard deviation
sd_mle(x) # [1] 0.9831864
```

As expected the MLE is not a conservative estimate for the standard deviation of a population based on a sample of that population.

Here is the result with your example vector.

```
x <- seq(from=1, to=10, by=1) #[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
sd(x) #[1] 3.02765
sd_mle(x) #[1] 2.872281
```